# Currying for dependent functions

Tags: functions, set-theory

[Currying and uncurrying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) is defined between functions in $Z^{X \times Y}$ (the first set) and $\left( Z^Y \right)^X$ (the second set).

But what if $Y$ is not a constant but is dependent on $X$?

The first set would become $Z^{\sum_{i\in X}Y_i}$.

What may be a proper expressing for the second set in the case of dependent $Y$?

Comment: Does $\Sigma$ refer to the coproduct in $\mathsf{Set}$?

Comment: @John Stalfos: Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that I found a solution myself:

the first set: $Z^{\sum_{i \in X} Y_i}$

the second set: $\prod_{i \in X} Z^{Y_i}$

Comment: In the Curry-Howard correspondence this corresponds to the logical equivalence of $\forall x (\phi (x)\Longrightarrow c)$ and $(\exists x \phi(x))\Longrightarrow c$.